# Circular Motion and Simulated Gravity

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, rotational-kinematics, centrifugal-force

People have proposed that a spinning cylindrical shape could be used to simulate gravity. Will gravity be simulated if the cylinder is frictionless? My brain can't seem to wrap around the idea that this could work if the cylinder is frictionless. Can anybody explain whether friction is required or not?

Comment: Where would that friction be that you are referring to?

Comment: friction between the ring and the objects on the ring. Like if people were on the ring, the friction between their shoes and the ring

Comment: Find a real frictionless surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friction is required for a spinning ring or cylinder to simulate gravity. The method works because the inner surface provides a tangential acceleration to objects that contact it, and then a radial (normal) acceleration to those objects which otherwise at this point would travel in a straight line tangent to the rotation. If the wall of the ring were frictionless, it would behave similarly to a non-rotating wall: objects would bounce off of it, but they wouldn't accelerate tangentially and thus wouldn't be forced into circular motion.